# How a method located inside a user control can access data from aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a series of user controls of the same type on the same aspx page. When each user control loads, I want it to check some information in the aspx page, for instance, who is logged in, which session it is, and son on.

For now, I'm returning a hard-codded value. **GetUserDBName()** is located inside the user control

```
private string GetUserDBName()
{
   return "UserDBName";
}
```

How does this method access data located in the aspx page that contains the user controls? And below is how the session is defined inside the aspx page.

```
private string strDBName = string.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  strDBName = Session["UserDBName"].Trim();
}
```

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

The parent page's name is **NewHireCheck.aspx**. The user control's name is **CheckListByDepartment.ascx**.

Comment: Will the parent ASPX page always be the same (or at least have the same code-behind class)?

Comment: I think so. We have created this user control just so simplifie the complexity of the page as many things are repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user control keeps a reference to the container page through the `Page` property.

So in your user control code you are allowed to do the below:

```
var resultFromPageMethod=((yourPageType)this.Page).APageMethod();
```

Comment: Page = User Control? YourPageType = ??? Where is the above code? Inside the user control?

Comment: in the user control code. youPageType is the class name of your page (code behind)